# PHPDoc equivalent in WebStorm for JSDoc?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

In *PhpStorm* is a *PHPDoc* tab in `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP`. Here you can customize the default comment blocks for classes.

**My question**

Is there a way to customize JSDoc in *WebStorm* this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not currently possible. Please feel free to vote for [WEB-13992](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13992) and linked tickets